# Type of Run Time Error

Tags: excel, runtime-error, vba

The below code give me this error:
`Class does not support automation or does not support expected interface`

Can anyone please explain Why am i getting this error

```
Sub typeofcheck()
Dim wks As New Worksheet

If TypeOf wks Is Worksheet Then
    MsgBox "This is Worksheet"
Else
    MsgBox "This is not"
End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in the `As New`.

AFAIK you can't create a new instance of a worksheet directly; you'll have to call the `Add` method in the `Sheets` collection for example:

```
Public Sub typeofcheck()
    Dim wks As Worksheet
    Set wks = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Add

    If TypeOf wks Is Worksheet Then
        MsgBox "This is Worksheet"
    Else
        MsgBox "This is not"
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if can explain, but i think you can fix your code by initializating of variable wks. Something like this

```
Sub typeofcheck()
Dim wks As New Worksheet
Set wks = Sheets("someFunnySheetName")


If TypeOf wks Is Worksheet Then
    MsgBox "This is Worksheet"
Else
    MsgBox "This is not"
End If
End Sub
```

IMHO the issue will be that with `DIM` you only alocate some memory, and with `Set` you will set datatype. But VBA is a kind of mistery. Once i tried to read something in MSDN documentation, and it was worse than hell...

edit1: i made some further test, and this nice error msg which you mention sounds very pro, but if you debug code, and hover about wks variable, it tells you that `wks = <Object variable or With block variable not set>` which is much more easier to read. So to future, try to debug, and hover your variables. And if you dont know what to do, try to few `Set`s :) VBA is about magic

Comment: @Well AFAIK with dim you declare the variable while with set we bring the object live, It is using set statement that memory is allocated to object.

Answer (score 0):

The error is caused by trying to access [an interface that isn't available](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3b6caf2h.aspx).

The correct way to do what you want is:

```
Sub typeofcheck()
Dim wks As Worksheet
Set wks = Worksheets.Add

Debug.Print TypeOf wks Is Worksheet
If TypeOf wks Is Worksheet Then
    MsgBox "This is Worksheet"
Else
    MsgBox "This is not"
End If
End Sub
```